# How to stop the timer?

Tags: java, timer

I tried to stop the timer but i haven't manage it. I need to stop the timer when label leaves the screen(x<0) and start the timer again to move the label from right to the left side of the frame.

```
private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
    for(int i=0;i<10;i++){
      x=365;   //horizontal position
      while(x>0){
      randPosition=(int) (Math.random() * 365);  // random vertical position
      y=randPosition;
      timer=new Timer(50,new ActionListener() {

            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
            jLabel1.setLocation(x,y);
            rand=(int)(Math.random()*10); //random speed to the left
            x=x-rand;
            }
             });
        timer.start();
         }
     }

    }
```

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Timer.html#cancel() ?

Comment: `while(x>0){` What is the purpose of the while loop? It will not terminate until after x <= 0, which won't happen because the Timers that decrement `x` will not be able to do so (as the EDT is already busy)

Answer (score 1):

The *outer* `ActionListener` **A** implementation continues in a while loop for `x` to decrement to a specific value (eg `while (x>0)`). This occurs on the `EDT`. The only code that seems to decrement `x` is within the `Timer`s generated, but a `Timer` runs its code on the `EDT`, so it has to wait for **A** to complete, so `x` is never decremented. In other words, with the information provided it is suggestive that the posted code deadlocks the EDT.

It is unclear exactly what you are after, but consider creating a single Timer that decrements X, and stops when a condition is met. For instance:

```
private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
    x=365;   //horizontal position
    y=(int) (Math.random() * 365);  // random vertical position
    final Timer timer=new Timer(50,new ActionListener() {

        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
            jLabel1.setLocation(x,y);
            rand=(int)(Math.random()*10); //random speed to the left
            x=x-rand;
            if ( x <= 0 ){
                timer.stop();
            }
        }
    });
    timer.start();
}
```